# Div wrapper not centering all page content

Tags: css, html

What is causing the following to not center the entire page?

```
  <html>

    <style type="text/css">
    .col {
        width: 250px; 
        float: left
    }
    </style>

    <body>

    <div style="width=500px;margin:0 auto;">

    <p style="float:left;text-align:right;width:120px;line-height: 26px;">

</p>

<p style="float:left;width:150px;margin-left:20px;">

</p>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div class="col">
<p>

</p>
</div>

<div class="col">
<p>

</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `width:500px` not `width=500px`.

You are using inline style which is a bad practice.

Write this:

```
.wrapper{width:500px;margin:0 auto;background:#eee;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4S8N9/)

Comment: Or even lose the wrapper div altogether and center with: html {text-align:center;} body {background:#eee;margin: 0 auto;width:500px;}

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason is because you have floated most of your `div`s. If you float everything and then use `margin: 0 auto;` it will be ineffective, *because* of the float property. Are you trying to make a certain column layout(2 or 3)?

Try using div's to create the columns and aligning them appropriately with the float properties